# Page redirecting before SQL has excuted - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a slightly modified AccountController that should write a row into a table upon login.

However, the page redirects before the DB action has completed and so nothing is inserted.

I've temporarily solved this by sticking in a Thread.Sleep, but I'm looking for an alternative that makes it appear seamless.

```
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) Then
        Return Redirect(returnUrl)
    Else
        Dim db As New GlobalSecModelDataContext
        Dim logAdmin = New secAdminLog
        logAdmin.EmployeeNumber = userName
        logAdmin.What = "Logged in"
        logAdmin.DateLogged = DateTime.Now
        logAdmin.UserIP = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
        logAdmin.NetworkUser = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_USER")

        db.secAdminLogs.InsertOnSubmit(logAdmin)
        db.SubmitChanges()
        Session("LoggedInUser") = StrConv(userName, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Return Redirect("/Home")
    End If
```

Is there a better solution that would be quicker for the user using the system or is using `Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)` the best way?

I'm finding `Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)` isn't perfect as the DB transaction doesn't always complete in that time.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your DB code do - anything special?

Comment: Nope, it's just as it is there. Creates a row for insertion with the data above and inserts it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your InsertOnSubmit and SubmitChanges into a transaction, and commit before the redirect. I have a lot of very similar code and don't see this issue. SubmitChanges() by default runs synchronously and will not return until the SQL has executed.